# Is "how every minutes" correct?

Tags: american-english, terminology

I am trying to say that a number X defines "how every minutes" the operation Y will take place.

That means, if the number X is 10, the operation Y will be performed every 10 minutes.

This is the actual context (it's a technical documentation):

`value="10": Sets how every minutes the operation will be performed`

Comment: In addition to Matt's suggestion: *Sets  **how often** (in minutes) the operation will be performed*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack But of course! "how often". Couldn't be simpler! I wonder how i missed this?! Post it as an answer I'll accept it :D

Comment: To answer the question in the title: "how every minutes" is not correct, and readers will be confused if you say "how every minutes".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to Matt's suggestion:

> Sets *how often* (in minutes) the operation will be performed.

*How often* refers to frequency. See [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/often) for *often* as in *How often do you get your hair cut?*, for example.

Comment: Since "how often" asks for a frequency, I would wonder whether the writer meant to say "sets how often (**per** minute) the operation will be performed". I prefer [Jon Petersons answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98252/is-how-every-minutes-correct/98275#98275), because it avoids this ambiguity.

Answer (score 9):

Technically, the time between each instance of a recurring event is the period. This is closely related to frequency, but frequency is the number of times a recurring event happens in a fixed time period (a second, unless specified otherwise).

So:

```
value="10": Sets period in minutes between each repeat operation
```

Would be ideal. You could also simply use the word 'time' instead of 'period',  in the example above and that would be correct idiomatic English, but slightly less precise in a technical document.

Answer (score 4):

The way you have it isn't quite correct. A better way to say it would be "Sets the frequency of the operation (in minutes)".

Comment: that's not a frequency, that's a period.

Comment: @njzk2 - True, if you're talking exact mathematical/scientific terminology. In everyday idiomatic use, Matt's answer is what I would expect to see.

Comment: Best not to use a term that has _polar opposite meanings_ depending on how "exactly" you read it.

Answer (score 1):

The value of 'X' sets the time, in minutes, between each operation 'Y'.

---

If 'X'=10, operation 'Y' will be performed every 10 minutes.

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify which of those first two sentences (or both?) you are suggesting for use?